# Getting Invalid AdamId: XXXXXXXX. error while trying to upload the ipa on testflight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, application-loader

I am getting *Invalid AdamId: XXXXXXXX* while trying to upload ipa on testflight using application loader.

Here are some more detail:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had this error because I didn't have "developer" authorization in iTunes Connect for this specific application.

Answer (score 0):

The AdamID is your application's ID. I had the same problem as you when I had forgotten to log in to the correct iTunes account inside the application loader.

Comment: you mean bundle id, it is same.